# Is $\frac{n}{\log n} \log \frac{n}{\log n} = O(n)$?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

I have an algorithm with this time complexity:

$$ T(n) = O(n) + \frac{n}{\log n} \cdot \log \frac{n}{\log n}. $$

I tried to figure out how to solve this
and I tried to say something like this :
if I have $\frac{\log n}{n}$ then the value is going to be very small, if I switch between them the value becomes very big,
so I came to this: $T(n) = O(n)+$ something very big.

I am trying to determine if the result is larger than linear time or not, but I am lost.

Comment: Don't use images for important content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $\log(\frac{n}{\log(n)}) \le \log(n)$.

Substitute this into the equation to get that $T=O(n)+\frac{n}{\log(n)}\left(\log\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)}\right)\right)\le O(n)+\frac{n}{\log(n)} \log(n)=O(n)+n=O(n)$

So $T=O(n)$, and indeed it is not bigger than linear time.

Comment: tank you sir ..

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of big-O:
$$f(n)=\mathcal{O}(n)$$
if there exists a positive constant real number $c$ that
$$  f(n)\leq cn.$$
I claim that
$$\frac{n}{\log n} \log \frac{n}{\log n} = \mathcal{O}(n)$$
So, for proving it we act as follow
$$\frac{n}{\log n} \log \frac{n}{\log n} \leq cn$$
multiply each side of inequality by   ${\log n}$:
$$n \log \frac{n}{\log n} \leq cn\log n$$
on the other hand we know that
as $n\to \infty$
$$\log \frac{n}{\log n}\leq \log n$$

$$\rightarrow\forall c\geq 1\hspace{10pt} n \log n \leq cn\log n. \square$$

So
$$\frac{n}{\log n} \log \frac{n}{\log n} = \mathcal{O}(n).$$

Answer (score 0):

Since we know
$$\log \frac{a}{b} = \log a - \log b
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaciiBaiaac+
% gacaGGNbWaaSaaaeaacaWGHbaabaGaamOyaaaacqGH9aqpciGGSbGa
% ai4BaiaacEgacaWGHbGaeyOeI0IaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOyaa
% aa!43F0!
$$
we can say:
$$\frac{n}{{\log n}}.\log \frac{n}{{\log n}} = \frac{n}{{\log n}}(\log n - \log \log n) = n - \frac{{n.\log \log n}}{{\log n}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaca
% WGUbaabaGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaaaacaGGUaGaciiBaiaa
% c+gacaGGNbWaaSaaaeaacaWGUbaabaGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaam
% OBaaaacqGH9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaad6gaaeaaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEga
% caWGUbaaaiaacIcaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaWGUbGaeyOeI0Iaci
% iBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaiaacMcacqGH
% 9aqpcaWGUbGaeyOeI0YaaSaaaeaacaWGUbGaaiOlaiGacYgacaGGVb
% Gaai4zaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaad6gaaeaaciGGSbGaai4Baiaa
% cEgacaWGUbaaaaaa!644A!
$$
on the other hand, we know clearly
$$\log \log n < \log n
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaciiBaiaac+
% gacaGGNbGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaiabgYda8iGacYgacaGG
% VbGaai4zaiaad6gaaaa!413D!
$$
hence:
$$\frac{{n.\log \log n}}{{\log n}} < \frac{{n.\log n}}{{\log n}} \to \frac{{n.\log \log n}}{{\log n}} < n \to \frac{{n.\log \log n}}{{\log n}} \in O\;(n)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaca
% WGUbGaaiOlaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zaiaa
% d6gaaeaaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaWGUbaaaiabgYda8maalaaaba
% GaamOBaiaac6caciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgacaWGUbaabaGaciiBaiaa
% c+gacaGGNbGaamOBaaaacqGHsgIRdaWcaaqaaiaad6gacaGGUaGaci
% iBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaaqaaiGacYga
% caGGVbGaai4zaiaad6gaaaGaeyipaWJaamOBaiabgkziUoaalaaaba
% GaamOBaiaac6caciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEgaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEga
% caWGUbaabaGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbGaamOBaaaacqGHiiIZcaWGpb
% GaaGjbVlaacIcacaWGUbGaaiykaaaa!7045!
$$
according to above explanation:
$$T\;(n) = O\;(n) + n - O\;(n) \to T\;(n) \in O\;(n)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamivaiaays
% W7caGGOaGaamOBaiaacMcacqGH9aqpcaWGpbGaaGjbVlaacIcacaWG
% UbGaaiykaiabgUcaRiaad6gacqGHsislcaWGpbGaaGjbVlaacIcaca
% WGUbGaaiykaiabgkziUkaadsfacaaMe8Uaaiikaiaad6gacaGGPaGa
% eyicI4Saam4taiaaysW7caGGOaGaamOBaiaacMcaaaa!5487!
$$